# Bound of squarefree part of an integer

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, factoring

I am studying the paper [DIOPHANTINE EQUATIONS OF THE FORM
$F(X) = G(Y)$ - AN EXPOSITION](https://www.isibang.ac.in/%7Esury/mskulksury.pdf) which discusses the result of Erdos and Selfridge.

I am unable to understand the highlighted statement ''Clearly each prime factor of each $a_i$ is less than $k$."

For example, if I take $n=49$ and $k=4$, then we have $50\cdot51\cdot52\cdot53 = y^2$ and $$50 = 2 \cdot 5^2, \quad \quad 51 = 3\cdot17, \quad \quad 52= 13\cdot2^2,  \quad \quad 53= 53.$$

Clearly, $13 \nleq 4.$ What am I misunderstanding here? Please help me.

[image]

Comment: Please don't use pictures of text or formulas. See
[here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/34121/why-image-cannot-be-used-for-explaining-my-maths-problem),
why. Use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The highlighted statement only applies if $r:=\prod_{i=1}^k a_i$ is a square, which is not the case in your example.

Let $p$ be prime factor of $a_i$ with $p \ge k$. Then $p$ divides $n+i$, but does not divide any other of the factors $n+1,..n+k$. Therefore, $p^2$ does not divide $r$, and $r$ is not a square, in contradiction to the assumption.